# Creating instance for non-existing object: <somenumber> | What Did I Do Wrong?

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language

Every time I run my little game, it throws me the following, fatal, error:

```
ERROR in
action number 2
of Trigger Event: 
for object obj_y:

Creating instance for non-existing object: 100012
```

I have no idea what's causing it. The only time I use obj_y, is in one file. When I comment that part out, it still keeps nagging it's non-existing.

My code:

```
var randomxnumber;
var randomynumber;
var randomarraynumber;
var array;
var snelheid;
snelheid = 3.5;

array[0] = obj_a;
array[1] = obj_b;
array[2] = obj_c;
array[3] = obj_d;
array[4] = obj_e;
array[5] = obj_f;
array[6] = obj_g;
array[7] = obj_h;
array[8] = obj_i;
array[9] = obj_j;
array[10] = obj_k;
array[11] = obj_l;
array[12] = obj_m;
array[13] = obj_n;
array[14] = obj_o;
array[15] = obj_p;
array[16] = obj_q;
array[17] = obj_r;
array[18] = obj_s;
array[19] = obj_t;
array[20] = obj_u;
array[21] = obj_v;
array[22] = obj_w;
array[23] = obj_x;
array[24] = obj_y;
array[25] = obj_z;

randomxnumber = random_range(0, 50);
randomynumber = random_range(-10, -50);
for (int = 0; int < 20; int += 1){
    if(randomxnumber >= window_get_width()){
        randomxnumber -= 100;
    } else {
        randomxnumber += 50;
    }
    randomynumber -= 50;
    array[int] = instance_create(randomxnumber, randomynumber, array[random_range(0, 26)]);
    with(array[int]){
        vspeed = snelheid;
    }
}
```

My obj_y object:
[image: obj_y object]

Quick note, I'm on GameMaker 8.1 Standard. I'm I being stupid and just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange code, I don't understand what you trying to do.

Although there are two errors.

```
array[random_range(0, 26)]
```

should be

```
array[irandom_range(0, 25)
```

GM rounds array's index, so if value is more than 25 (25.1, etc) you will have out of array bounds.

Second.

```
array[int] = instance_create(...)
```

There instance's id will be stored into array. Not object's id. But `instance_create` requires object index. You can get object's index using `object_index` variable:

```
array[int] = instance_create(randomxnumber, randomynumber, array[irandom_range(0, 25)].object_index);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help, but it isn't working. First of all, when I add .object_index, it gives me an error:

EXECUTION ERROR in creation code of room level1
Error in code at line 62:
       array[int] = instance_create(randomxnumber, randomynumber, array[irandom_range(0, 25)].object_index);
                                                                                              ^
at position 93: Unknown variable object_index

I did add the irandom_range, but that didn't fix my issue

Comment: Describe what are you trying to do.

Comment: Are `obj_a`, `obj_b`, etc objects? Or instances? If they are objects, of course it won't work, because then you mix objects and instances. For example, if you will write result into another array, it will work: `data[int] = instance_create(randomxnumber, randomynumber, array[irandom_range(0, 25)]);`